# How do I associate two entries in a database that are connected through a many-to-many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-6

How do I associate two entries in a database that are connected through a many-to-many relationship in Rails?

I'm trying to associate Users and Issues for an issue tracker. I'm using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, not `:through`. I have a `:user_id` and `:issue_id` available to me, but there doesn't seem to be `User.issues.find(id)` or `Issue.users.find(id)` available to me. I have a route `post "/", to: "home#create"`. I'm trying to make a `create` method in home_controller.rb. [image: My DB mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it you're calling the method on the `User` class and not an instance.

If you want to get the issues connected to a user you need to fetch the user first:

```
User.find(id).issues
```

If you want to add a record to the association you can use the shovel method or any of the methods [generated by the association macro](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

```
User.find(id).issues << Issue.find(3)
User.find(id).issues.push(Issue.find(3))
User.find(id).issue_ids = [1, 2, 3]
```

Besides that you have a smattering of naming issues in your schema. Use `snake_case` **everywhere** in your database schema unless you have a good reason why you want to break [the conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record) and feel like explicitly configuring table and foreign key names.

I would also really question if you really want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. It should only really be used if you can't foresee that you ever will need to add additional attributes to the join table or never need to query the table directly - it seems pretty unrealistic that that would be true in an issue tracker. You want `has_many through:` - [pretty much always](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many).

> I have a route post "/", to: "home#create". I'm trying to make a
> create method in home_controller.rb.

Don't throw everything into a junk drawer controller. Think about your app in terms of resources that can be CRUD:ed and create controllers that handle *just that resource*. You should think about what the relation between a user and an issue is in your domain and how you can model it as an actual entity in the domain logic instead of just plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all I need to do is direct you to [Rails Guides: Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference).

There is neither of these

```
User.issues.find(id)
Issue.users.find(id)
```

because when you are finding an issue or user by id, you don't use the association.  Instead use these:

```
Issues.find(id)
Users.find(id)
```

Since the `:id` is unique this will work and should be what you want.

The only time you want to query issues or users using the association will be when you have the data for the other end of the relationship.

```
user = User.find(user_id)
issue = user.issues.where(id: issue_id)
```

Since the `:id` field is unique, this is the same as `Issues.find(id)`.  However if you want to get a collection of a user's issues with some other data, you can put the condition for that data in the `where`.

You can create an issue for a user this way:

```
user = User.find(user_id)
issue = User.issues.create( ... )
```